# $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$. then $S_{2^n}$=?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S_n$=$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$. which of the following is true?

1. $S_{2^n}\ge\frac{n}{2}$ for every n$\ge1$.
2. $S_n$ is a bounded sequence.
3. $|S_{2^n}-S_{2^{n-1}}|\to0$ as n$\to\infty$.
4. $\frac{S_n}{n}\to1$ as n$\to\infty$.

I have a confusion that whether $S_{2^n}$=$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}$? 
or
$S_{2^n}$=$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}$?

Comment: The second interpretation. And number 3 is true.

Comment: Your second interpretation is correct. Notice that $S_{2^n} - S_{2^{n-1}} = a_{2^n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Obviously $S_{2^n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: i think options 1 and 2 are also true. m i right?

Comment: No. If 1 holds then the sequence is not bounded

Comment: Your question was already discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585341/s-n-sum-k-1n-frac1k-then-is-s-n-bounded)

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as off topic, the OP is active in the question (it could be closed as a duplicate but that's a whole another story).

Comment: Only 1 is correct according to me. 2 and 3 could be easily rejected by the divergence nature of harmonic series, while 4 is trivially wrong by using the formula $H_n =\ln n +O(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second interpretation is correct: $S_{2^n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Hint for your questions: note that
$$S_{2^{n+1}}=S_{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^n+k}\geq S_{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^n+2^n}=S_{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Hence $S_{2^{n+1}}-S_{2^{n}}\geq 1/2$ and 3) is false.

Show by induction that 1) holds and therefore 2) is false. 
What about 4)?

P.S. 4) is false. We have that
$$S_{2^{n+1}}=S_{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{2^n+k}< S_{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{k}=2S_{2^{n}}.$$ 
Hence the sequence $(S_{2^{n}}/2^n)_n$ is positive and strictly decreasing.Therefore it converges to a non-negative limit $L$. Since $S_{1}/1=1$ it follows that $L<1$  which contradicts 4).

Comment: Now i understood the question properly. there are more than one term between $s_{2^n}$ and $S_{2^{n-1}}$. 4) is not true

Comment: Yes, 4) is false. Have you a proof?

Comment: here $a_n$=$\frac{1}{2^n}\to0$ as n$\to\infty$ then by cauchy's first theorem on limits $\frac{S_n}{n}\to0$ as n$\to\infty$. m i right?

Comment: OK. This is a way to show it.

Comment: @Priyanka I gave another proof that 4) is false (see my PS). Any more doubts?

Answer (score 1):

$3)$ and $4)$ can be rejected by using the formula $H_n=\ln{n}+\gamma+O(n^{-1})$. That is: $$3) \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left[H_{2^n}-H_{2^{n-1}}\right]=\ln2$$
$$4)\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{H_n}{n}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln{n}+\gamma+O(n^{-1})}{n}=0$$